# set charset in react project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, charset

I want to render the text of an API response in plain/text format directly, but I always print the "?"

I have tried the webpack plugin

```
  plugins:[
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: './build/index.html'
  }),
  new EncodingPlugin({
     encoding: 'ISO-8859-15'
   })
```

]

and define de charset on index.html

React call api code:

```
fetch(`${url}`, {

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-15',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(response => {
            setInfo(response.toString())
            setLoading(false);
        });
```

the result:

```
METEOROLOG�A
```

any ideas to solve the format? I have tried to set font-family in element tag ""
but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Try removing the content-type header, and/or specifically `;charset=ISO-8859-15` , that's a weird thing to request

Comment: can you console log what response.toString() is?

Comment: I try to remove all charset but everything remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using `charset=ISO-8859-15` . But maybe it's the reason why you're getting this error ( The question marks here are a problem because they represent values in your  data that are not valid characters  ) you're getting a difference in  **Character Encoding**

Possible solution : get rid of `charset=ISO-8859-15`

Comment: Hi!I try to remove all charset but everything remains the same..
remove it charset from index.html, from webpack and header request.
**NETWORK DEBUG**
`Request URL: https://opendata.aemet.es/opendata/sh/0903dee6`
`Request Method: GET`
`Status Code: 200 OK`

`Accept: */*`
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`
`aemet_estado: 200`
`Connection: close`
`Content-Length: 1298`
`Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-15`

`Accept: */*`
`Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`
`Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9`
`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET`

Comment: instead of `'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-15',` try `'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',` Your api call is ok everything seems to be working fine it's just the encoding  who makes this error

Comment: I use axios to get data from api and the problem no longer exists. I don't understand why fetch doesn't work fine or is that I did not configure the header correctly.

thanks  for all!